# Can't modify a UIView that was created in storyboard

Tags: ios7, uiview, storyboard

I'm trying to modify a view created in the storyboard. I can read and log the properties of the view (like the frame -- see below) and they are as expected so I'm sure I have a valid reference to the view. I want to do various modifications including change its background color and its affine transform and add a label to it but I can't get any modification to work.

Some code:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.storyboardVC = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
self.viewA = [self.storyboardVC.view viewWithTag:77];
NSLog(@"\nVC: %@\nviewA: %@", self.storyboardVC, self.viewA);

self.viewA.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
CGRect r = CGRectMake(100, 25, 50, 50);
UILabel *tag = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:r];
tag.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
tag.text = @"tag";
[self.viewA addSubview:tag];
```

The dimensions are such that the tag label should fit inside viewA but the "tag" label never appears. Also the background color never changes. I made viewA alpha = 0.4 so I could see if tag label goes behind it, but no. All views have userInteractionEnabled and have autoresize subviews checked in the storyboard.

I also tried other programmatic modifications but they all failed to do anything. It's as if the view is read-only.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing is that Cocoa is a framework. You have to understand what it is doing and work *with* it, not against it.

The problem here is that this is not a legitimate way to work with a view controller and its view:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.storyboardVC = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
self.viewA = [self.storyboardVC.view viewWithTag:77];
```

You are arbitrarily pulling out (instantiating) a view controller (`storyboardVC`) and working with its view (`viewA`), but that view controller is not part of your app's view controller hierarchy and the view is not part of its view hierarchy - none of this is happening in your app's interface. So naturally you don't see anything. You do all this on an invisible copy that is just thrown away. (You cannot use code to change the storyboard itself, you know; the *storyboard* is indeed read-only.)

To make changes in your view that you can actually see, wait until the framework tells you that the view is about to appear in the interface (e.g. your view controller's `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`). That is what these kinds of lifetime event messages are for.

Comment: The code I'm showing is in my app's view controller's viewDidAppear:animated. Isn't that the right place?

Comment: But then the view is already `self.view` — the one you are pulling out of the storyboard is, as I said, a copy you are creating and discarding. For example, perhaps you mean `[self.view viewWithTag:77]`.

Comment: I thought about your comments several times and had an epiphany. You didn't put your finger on my fundamental misunderstanding but you helped me see it. I never realized until now that when I start a project, the class named "ViewController" that is included in my project is the class of which the top ViewController in the storyboard is an instance. (I think that's the way to say it.) I now see that when the storyboard ViewController is selected its class is identified as the custom class ViewController, not UIViewController.

Comment: I've been doing Xcode and iOS for a couple of years now (since Xcode 3) and never got this. Most of that time I used cocos2d and never used storyboard or InterfaceBuilder so when I started with storyboard a lot of it seemed magical. I doubt that a clear explanation of the ViewController object in the storyboard appears explicitly anywhere in the Apple documentation.

Comment: @RobertL if you look at my bio you will see that I have attempted to remedy that... :)